# DatagridComboBoxColumn Sort

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, sorting, xaml, datagridcomboboxcolumn

XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Department" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource departmentViewSource}}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Title" SelectedValuePath="ID" SortDirection="Ascending"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding DepartmentID, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SortMemberPath="lkpDepartments.Sequence" />
```

It appears to display the correct text, and link to the GUID correctly.  But every variation that I have tried will not present the dropdown in order by the Sequence field (an int, no nulls, unique).  Similar posts here aren't duplicates, because I'm using their solution and it still doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to the sort order of the rows in the DataGrid or in each ComboBox?

Comment: The order of the items in the dropdown itself, thanks.

Comment: Sort departmentViewSource then.

Comment: That would change its order everywhere it's used, correct?  So are you saying I need a separate viewsource for the combobox, so that it won't change the behavior of the maintenance grid?  Why does SortMemberPath not work correctly?

Comment: SortMemberPath applies to the DataGrid. It decides the property to sort by when you click on the column header.

Comment: If you put that in as the answer (define another viewsource just for the combobox and sort the items there), then I can mark that as the answer to this question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SortMemberPath` applies to the `DataGrid`. It decides the property to sort by when you click on the column header.

To sort the `ComboBox`, you should sort `departmentViewSource`. You can for example do this by adding a `SortDescription` to it in your XAML markup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-sort-and-group-data-using-a-view-in-xaml.

If you are using the same `CollectionViewSource` elsewhere and want different sort orders, you should define another one and bind the `ComboBox` to this.